# How to use text editors in /var/www without being asked for a password

Tags: permissions, files, filesystem, 17.10

I want to use *PHPStorm* or *Sublime Text* to change files in `/var/www` directory.

But in *PHPStorm* I can't even open files and in *Sublime Text* I can open, view and change files, but it always asks for my password when I save it.

**How I can do this without always being asked for a password?**

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -la /var/www`

Comment: @NerdOfCode, https://pastebin.com/rTTmL8WG

Comment: :) Great to hear that

Answer (score 0):

That directory and it's files are probably not owned by your user, or it's group.

Adding your user to the group that owns the directory and/or the files will likely allow you to do that. However that's a bad solution. A good solution would be do your work on a directory within your home directory and then deploy  the work to /var/www if needed.

Most modern web frameworks allow to run a development server on an unprivileged port and serving specifically only the project were you're working on. Alternatively configure your web server to serve a vhost for a directory that contains your project within your home directory.

Comment: Alternatively, unless the application is modifying it's files, it can be owned by user, and `www-data` can have read and execute permission on it. If uploads are used, `www-data` can have write access to the upload location and no more. From a security standpoint, this is desirable, as an attacker cannot exploit the web-server to inject code into files...

Comment: So which commands should I write to the terminal?

Comment: This are some possible ideas but as the OP said could you please add the necessary procedures to make your answer more valuable.